# Understanding DataTorrent with example

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-streaming, apache-apex

I am supposed to work on [DataTorrent](https://www.datatorrent.com/) and looking for articles/documentation to go through. I could not find detailed documentation on what are operators, how are they used for processing our data and about MALHAR library which is being used in operators (not sure about this part). Can somebody help me in understanding about DataTorrent by suggesting references for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are new links for the docs

DataTorrent
http://docs.datatorrent.com/

Apache Apex
http://apex.incubator.apache.org/docs.html

The following mailing lists are available for Apex:
dev@apex.incubator.apache.org is for people who want to contribute code to Apex. 
users@apex.incubator.apache.org is a discussion forum for people who want to build apps and/or solutions using Apex

Answer (score 2):

- Malhar Operator Developer guide: https://www.datatorrent.com/docs/guides/OperatorDeveloperGuide.html
- If you want to develop a connector, under the’ io’ package on github, you will see a bunch of our existing connectors that you might be able to re-purpose.: https://github.com/DataTorrent/Malhar/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/datatorrent/lib/io
- if you have any questions about our Malhar library and developing a connector, please send an email to our email group:  malhar-users@googlegroups.com